# going through each cell in a column and reset its value if >0

Tags: google-apps-script

When I open a google sheet, I'd like all values within one specific column to be reset to 0 if its value is >0.
Please note that some cells contain no data, I wouldn't like to mess up with these cells as they should stay empty.
At the moment I'm really trying to build up an MVP so if I have to hardcode the value of the column within the formula it's OK.

I've made some research and tried to find relevant examples here, I've tweaked one snippet which works for one specific cell, now I'd like to learn how to automate the execution of this script so I don't have to hardcode each cell....

Here is the script I have

```
function onOpen() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = doc.getRange("B4");
    var value = cell.getValue();

    if (value > 0) {
        cell.setValue("0");
    }
    else {
        cell.setValue("0");
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate if you could help me a bit with this one by either poiting me in the right direction or showing me a working example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
//function onOpen() {
function makeZero() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');

  var theLastRow = theSheet.getLastRow();
  //Get all values from column A
  var theColumnRng = theSheet.getRange(1, 1, theLastRow, 1);
  //Get all the values from column A.  The return from getValues()
  //is a two dimensional array
  var theColumnValues = theColumnRng.getValues();
  var thisCellValue = "";

  var i;
  for (i=0;i<theColumnValues.length;i++) {
    //Every inner array only has one element, therefore, index zero
    thisCellValue = theColumnValues[i][0]; 
    if (thisCellValue > 0) {
      theColumnValues[i][0] = 0;
    }; //No "else" condition needed.  If not greater than zero, do nothing
  };

  //Reset the entire column's values all at once
  theColumnRng.setValues(theColumnValues);
};
```

Comment: Hi Sandy, thanks a lot for this code. I've edited the value of ss.getSheetByName so I can pick my own sheet, var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy test version'); and I've also changed   var theColumnRng = theSheet.getRange(3, 2, theLastRow, 1); so It can start with column B and row 3. Now when I press the "run" button it works like a charm, however when I open the file again it doesn't trigger the function. Do you have any idea why do I have to trigger the script manually? Thanks

Comment: I changed the function name from `onOpen()` to something else.  Change it back to `onOpen()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare it with another column.
Please select sheet name, i (row ) number and col number accordingly (i,2) 2 is a col here. IF there is no col then put Val2=0 in your case. Also don't forget to edit the setValue also.

```
function ifelse_col_comparision(){
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  for(var i=2;i<ss.getLastRow();i++){
    var val1=ss.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var val2=ss.getRange(i,3).getValue();
  if(val2 >= val1){ss.getRange(i,4).setValue('Bigger or 0');}
  
  else{ss.getRange(i,4).setValue('lower or -1');}


  }
}
```

Please ask if you are looking for something else.